# How to plot several barplots using seaborn with respect to row?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Let's consider the data following:

```
accuracies_in = ([0.5959219858156029, 0.5736842105263158, 0.5670212765957447, 0.3])
accuracies_out = [0.5, 0.6041666666666666, 0.2, 0.4]
auc_out = [0.5182608695652174, 0.6095652173913042, 0.5, 0.7]
algorithm = ["Logistic Regression", "Decision Tree", "Random Forest", "Neural Network"]
frame = pd.DataFrame([accuracies_in, accuracies_out, auc_out])
frame.index = ["accuracies_in", "accuracies_out", "auc_out"]
frame.columns = algorithm
```

[image]

I want to have a barplot which will show results for those three characteristics (`accuracies_in`, `accuarcies_out` and `auc_out`). In other words on the barplot I want to group barplots more or less like this:

[image]

The first group (first row - `accuracy_in`) will contain four bars - `accuracies_in` for Logistic Regression, Decision Tree, Random Forest and Neural Network. Second group of bars will contain again four bars but this time for second row - `accuracies_out`. And lastly - the third group of bars will contain four bars with `auc_out` in each of them.

Could you please help me how it can be done? I searched a lot of questions but I couldn't find anything which will plot barplots with respect to rows. Could you please give me a hand in this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your dataframe to [long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data), using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# frame: given dataframe

df = frame.melt(var_name='Algorithm', value_name='Accuracy', ignore_index=False)
sns.set()
sns.barplot(data=df, x=df.index, y='Accuracy', hue='Algorithm')
```

[image: sns.barplot from long dataframe]

Answer (score 1):

You really have almost nothing to do but using the pandas builtin [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
frame.plot.bar()
```

input `frame`:

```
                Logistic Regression  Decision Tree  Random Forest  Neural Network
accuracies_in              0.595922       0.573684       0.567021             0.3
accuracies_out             0.500000       0.604167       0.200000             0.4
auc_out                    0.518261       0.609565       0.500000             0.7
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Or `frame.plot.bar(width=0.8, rot=0)`

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is something like:

```py
X = frame.index

X_axis = np.arange(len(X))
dist = 0.2
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.bar(X_axis + (-1)* dist, frame["Logistic Regression"], dist, label = 'accuracies_in')
plt.bar(X_axis + 0 * dist, frame["Decision Tree"], dist, label = 'accuracies_out')
plt.bar(X_axis + 1 * dist, frame["Random Forest"], dist, label = 'auc_out')
plt.bar(X_axis + 2 * dist, frame["Neural Network"], dist, label = 'auc_out')
  
plt.xticks(X_axis, X)
plt.xlabel("X axis")
plt.ylabel("Y axis")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

##### Output

[image: Your desired plot]